# Does the line "writing in the time of covid-19" reference some work of literature?

Tags: meaning, wording-choice

Someone sent me this literature joke but I don't get it, can someone help me please?
He wrote:

> *writing in the time of covid-19

Apparently the joke has something to do with literature, so if anyone understands it, can they please explain it?

Comment: Was this said in reference to anything, or can you give us any context at all? Without knowing more, it's impossible to tell what he meant, or that this is even supposed to be a joke.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add more context to your question? Or is the phrase "writing in the time of covid-19" the entire message? (Searching [writing in the time of covid-19](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22writing+in+the+time+of+covid-19%22&t=ffab&ia=web) gives a lot of results; it is not clear at all why that phrase in isolation would be a joke.)

Comment: As it's been two days and OP has not come back to reply to the above comments so I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely a reference to the title of Gabriel García Márquez's novel, *Love in the Time of Cholera*. "[noun] in the time of Covid-19" has become commonplace enough to be cliché now.